# access to Realm instance in overriding init

Tags: ios, swift, realm, init

i am overriding init() using Realm framework , and i can get access to Realm instance

example:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import RealmSwift

 class Order: Object {
  dynamic var address = ""

convenience init(content: String)
    {
        self.init(content: content)

    }

    convenience init(blahblah: String)
    {
     self.init()
     self.address = (realm!.objects(Order).first?.address)!
    }
```

then i am call init

var instance = Order(blahblah: "")

using blablah its a method to call required init.And then i have an error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

for this:

```
self.address = (realm!.objects(Order).first?.address)!
```

as i can see in debugger, there is no Realm instance. 
How to get access for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! I am not declare 'Realm' instance in this function.

```
 convenience init(blahblah: String)
    {
     self.init()
     let realm = realmAndPath()
     self.address = (realm.objects(Order).first?.address)!
    }
```

where realmAndPath() it's my function that returns 'Realm()'